# Восстановление БД из bak-файла

Tags: sql-server, sql

Здравствуйте. У меня возник такой вопрос: есть файл бэкапа  базы sql в фрмате .bak? лежащий на одном компьютере. Мене нужно восстановить базу данных из этого бэкапа на другом компьютере. Можно ли это сделать скриптом, и если да, то как? Заранее спасибо

Comment: А версии серверов одинаковы?

Comment: да. одинаковы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

команда T-SQL RESTORE DATABASE
запустить ее из командной строки есть sqlcmd